# FutureBuilder The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im getting this error in my dart code. If I delete coverImage widget , It gives error for other snapshat.data`s widget

**My Error**

> Exception caught by widgets library
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(dirty, state:
> _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>#45e11):
> The method '[]' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling:

[image]

The way Im using data.

```
image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: (snapshot.data['coverImage']).isEmpty
                    ? AssetImage('assets/background.png')
                    : NetworkImage(snapshot.data['coverImage']),
              ),
```

**My flutter doctor**
[image: My Flutter DOCTOR]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi in your switch statement you are not doing anything, so you are not filtering in which state the futurebuilder is and thus trying to access the data when its not already completed:

```
    return FutureBuilder(builder: ( context,  snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData){
        return ListView();
        
      }else if (snapshot.hasError){
        return Center(child:Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
      }
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());



    }
```

Here the three principal states are taken care of.

Comment: I just realized this now and fixed than come to here for give answer but you already did :) thank you dude.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your snapshot data is null
Maybe you should handle it with **?** or **== null**

```
image: (snapshot?.data['coverImage']).isEmpty
```

or

```
final dataCoverImage = snapshot.data['coverImage']

image: (dataCoverImage == null) || (dataCoverImage.isEmpty)
? AssetImage('assets/background.png')
: NetworkImage(snapshot.data['coverImage']),
```

Answer (score 0):

check if **['coverImage']** is there in your database your error shows that this field is not in your database
you can check in the code by

### (snapshot.data['coverImage']).isEmpty || snapshot.data['coverImage'] ==null)